# x86 assembly code push ebx -- segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm currently learning x86 asm, somehow if use "push ebx" it will trigger "segmentation fault", but if i use "push bx" the program will run and listen to the port. i tried to debug with gdb, i didn't find anything suspicious, ebx = 0x2. i really no idea why, can someone help to explain? (my system is ubuntu 12 x86)

```
global _start

section .text

_start:

  ; zero out registers
  xor eax, eax
  xor ebx, ebx
  xor ecx, ecx

  ; socket
  mov al, 0x66   ; syscall socketcall
  inc bl         ; SYS_SOCKET 1

  push ecx       ; socket(domain, type, protocol) -- protocol 0
  push ebx       ; type SOCK_STREAM -- 1
  push byte 0x2  ; domain -- AF_INET -- 2

  mov ecx, esp
  int 0x80

  ;mov edi, eax   ; save the return value into edi
  xchg edi, eax

  ; bind
  mov al, 0x66     ; syscall socketcall
  pop ebx          ; SYS_BIND 2 -- take from stack above AF_INET
  push esi
  push word 0xfb20 ; sin_port
  push ebx          ; AF_INET 2 <<<<<<< IF I CHANGE TO "PUSH BX" it won't segmentation fault
  mov ecx, esp     ; point ecx to the stack

  push 0x10        ; sizeof struct
  push ecx         ; sockaddr addr
  push edi         ; previous socket fd
  mov ecx, esp     ; point ecx to stack
  int 0x80

  ; listen
  mov al, 0x66     ; syscall socketcall
  mov bl, 0x4      ; SYS_LISTEN
  push edx         ; backlog arg listen 0
  push edi         ; previous socket
  mov ecx, esp     ; point ecx to stack
  int 0x80

  ; accept
  mov al, 0x66
  xor edx, edx
  push edx
  push edx
  push edi
  inc ebx
  int 0x80

  xchg ebx, eax
```

Comment: I don't see you set up a stack?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Linux sets up a stack for you, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: Which assembler are you programming for?

Comment: @fuz linux nasm

Comment: It doesn't crash there on my machine.  Instead, it crashes later because the `bind` call fails, thus setting the high-order bits of eax.  Since you never update them, the next few system calls get a wrong number.  Check with `strace`.

Comment: @fuz you're right !, thank you so much!, if i use push ebx on bind, the argument become wrong.